# Join 2 tables linked by a 0..n / 0..n relation with PHP Doctrine ORM

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, query-builder

I have 2 tables : `User` and `Series`.
There is also another table: `User_Series` that symbolize what series a user follow. Since this table symbolize just a relation `0..n --- 0..n`, a class for it wasn't generated.

```
User table:         Series table:       User_Series table:

| id      | ... |   | id      | ... |   | user_id | series_id |
|---------|-----|   |---------|-----|   |---------|-----------|
| INT(11) | ... |   | INT(11) | ... |   | INT(11) | INT(11)   |
```

How can I create a QueryBuilder that retrieves all the series that an user follow?

What I've tried and doesn't work (all series are returned):

```php
$this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Series::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->join(User::class, 'u')
    ->where('u = :user_id')
    ->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId())
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  Is your User::id property really user_id or id?  It might be easier (conceptually) to start with the user repository and then left join the Series class.  But just glancing at what you posted, I would expect it to work except for maybe the user_id vs id issue.

Comment: I've got no error. It's just that the query retrieves all the series. User::id is the ID of the User and user_id is the name that I gave to the parameter. Changing the parameter name to id doesn't work either.

Comment: Also, when starting with the user repository, the query retrieves users and not series.

Comment: where('u.id = :user_id') might get you a bit further.  And if you did swap the order then just return $user->getSeries()

Comment: Replaced `u` by `u.id` but the result is the same. I can't start from User because the execution part is handled by other functions that will add some filters (I simplified the problem here).

Comment: You lost me at "simplified the problem".

Comment: What I mean is that I showed you the problematic part only.

Comment: Hey. Show the classes User and Series, if available, it will be easier to understand what the problem is. Your request should look something like this ->join('s.user', 'u')->where('u.id = :user_id')

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the problem came from the join. It works now. Do you want to post the answer or should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0..n/0..n relation between the tables A and B is symbolised by another table inside the database.
However, Doctrine models it by a an array of A inside the B class and an array of B inside the A class.

So, when joining, it has to be done using that array.

```php
// finds all series that a specific user follows:
$this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Series::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->join('s.user', 'u')            // using s.user instead of User::class
    ->where('u = :user_id')
    ->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId())
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```